# How do I create custom Cortana commands that overlap with the built in ones?

Tags: c#, cortana, cortana-skills-kit

I've found instructions on how to create custom commands for Cortana using C# and Visual Studio 2017. Unfortunately, none explains what happens when the commands you want to use overlap with the built-in commands.

I want to control some of my audio/video equipment with Cortana, but I'm surely going to overlap with the built-in commands without a little preparation work. I'd prefer not to use long or hard to remember command names if I can avoid it. I'd like to use something like "Play music" or "Adjust volume" without it getting confused.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you looking to use simple invocation names that you worry might map to Cortana native skills and abilities e.g. "set a reminder" is an example where I can see it isn't something a 3rd party skill could use. If so, for now we don't have a solution beyond making sure your invocation names are unique.

If you are referring to something other than invocation names when you say 'commands' do clarify.

Comment: Your answer contained exactly what I was looking for. I can't just use "Next Song" or "Pause" for media controls. Thanks for answering this.